# c, c++ most basic double quotes

Tags: c++, c

```
char* a="HELLO WORLD";
```

IF ADDRESS of 'H' is 0x01 then the printf with %s prints to D but if the same code is written with manual printing routine

```
while(*a!=NULL) {printf("%c",n[a]);n++;}
```

this prints a few more characters..
but

`printf("%s",a);`

prints it perfectly.

```
while(*a++) printf("%c", *(a-1)); or 

for(;*a++;)printf("%c", *(a-1));
```

although work but i dont want solutions but the process mechanisms..

so the question coming to my mind is

whether printf gets the length of the string from some register(or any memory unit)
or it performs character check.. then prints...

Comment: i may be having some code error ...neglect them if u can...

Comment: I think you may just be.

Comment: What's n? Please provide a complete code sample.

Comment: Don't ask two unrelated questions in a single "question".

Comment: int n=0; i dont have programming error but marcelos struck off my question.....
i wanted to know about printf(const char*,...); feature....
marcelos u r requested to bring it back

Comment: @programming-tornado: It is totally unrelated to the question being asked. Hence ask a new question (first search in SO, it might have been already asked) for that.

Comment: What is D? Please don't ask incoherent questions

Comment: @programming-tornado: In fact it is already asked. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739496/how-does-the-c-compiler-implement-functions-with-variable-numbers-of-arguments

Answer (score 7):

The way you're indexing into the character string is odd.  It works for the string, but won't stop because you never change the value of *a.  What your program does is try to get the `a` offset of `n`, so for the first 11 positions they are the same, but the loop doesn't terminate because `*a` will always be `'H'`.  What you'd want the terminating condition to be is `n < strlen(a)`.

However, the more succinct way to write that program would be:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *a = "HELLO WORLD";
    while(*a) printf("%c", *a++);
    return 0;
}
```

This works because `a` is an array of characters and as we're printing out each character (de-referencing the value stored at the position) we also increment to the next position.  The string should terminate with a NULL reference, which will cause the loop to terminate sine `*a == 0` at the NULL terminator.

Comment: +1 I think this is an elegant answer because it doesn't require another integer counting value and uses pointer arithmetic

Answer (score 6):

did you mean or you have error:

```
int main() {
   int n = 0;
   char* a="HELLO WORLD";

   while(a[n] != NULL) {printf("%c",a[n]);n++;}
}
```

explanation about what is wrong:

```
while(*a!=NULL) printf("%c",n[a]);n++;
```

1. `a` is not modified anywhere, so `*a` will not change it's value.
2. Although `n[a]` is perfectly valid construct in C I strongly recommend not to use it, because it is *semantically* incorrect. You access array by index, not index by array.
3. You increment index (`n++`) but check the pointer to array. You could possibly increment `a` inself like this: `while(*a!=NULL) {printf("%c",*a);a++;}`

Comment: @Naveen: Good catch. Otherwise it prints H forever until it fails.

Comment: +1 for good answer, but you should explain **why** your code is correct.

Comment: question is not syntax error related I Know upto C Graphics development ,so i am not a beginner,but i asked this questiopn cause i wanted to know about printf...

Comment: except in step 3 you need two curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

The corect way to do this is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char *a="HELLO WORLD";
    int n = 0;
    while(a[n]!=NULL){
        cout<<a[n];
        n++;
    }

   cout<<'\n';
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @cristy:-please read the whole question first..
if I were to use C++...

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
typedef std::string String;
int main() {
    String afg="HELLO WORLD";
 std::cout<<afg;
   return 0;
}

Comment: @porgramming-tornado
I don't get what you're saying? You didn't mention any programming language in your question and the tags say: "c++,c"... So I thought a C++ version would help.

Your actual question makes no sense, because your program is not working properly cause of the strange iteration you make through the string letters. The "n" you use I think you wanted to use as an integer to iterate, but when you write "n[a]" makes no sense...

Comment: And pritf prints only what you ask it to print.
If you use printf(%s) it will print the whole string.
If you use printf(%c) it will print only a char, the reason your program doesn't output what it should is that your outputting algorithm is wrong, not the "printf" function...

Comment: the question had all the stuffs in the last two lines. if you had seen it totally..
my question was a rough pseudo code but u guys took it as program
snippet.furthermore i never asked about that specific programs output....n[a] works look at the program again copy it and run it...
nothing is strange ,everything is normal..

Comment: -1 for using `using namespace std;` instead of `using std::cout;`.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I remember, by default when you created `char* a` it will be something as `{HELLO WORLD\0}` in memory ('\0' is how %s know the end of the your string is)..

Not sure if `'\0' == null` will yield true.. but I doubt it

Comment: @Phil: The integer value 0 is not the null pointer constant.  In particular, even if he were incrementing `a` in his code, `*a!=NULL` is the wrong condition, since `*a` is not a pointer type.  `0` is converted to the null pointer constant in pointer contexts by the compiler, but not the other way round.

Comment: @Alok: the OP is confusing C and C++. In C++, NULL is the null pointer constant, and it's a macro for a constant integral 0. Could be `0L`, could be `false`, but usually just `0`. So there it works.

Comment: So, to summarize that, '\0' == null will yeild false? Did I get you right?

Comment: In general, '\0' == NULL is true. However, it is not a requirement. This could be due to the fact that the system is not using ascii, or that the null pointer is not found at (void*)0.